# Перевести число X в системе счисления s1 в систему счисления s2

Tags: python

Цель: написать универсальную программу, которая решает задачу для любых X, s1 и s2..

Входные данные:
Во входных данных вашей программе дается 3 числа: исходное число X, основания систем счисления s1 и s2 (2  ≤  s1, s2  ≤  10). Число X в десятичной системе счисления не превышает 2 × 109.

Выходные данные:
В выходных данных должно находиться одно число, равное числу X в системе счисления s2, или -1, если входные данные некорректны.
Мой код:

```
x, s1, s2 = map(int,input().split())
x = str(x)
x1 = int(x, s1)
if s2 == 10:
    print(x1)
else:
    s = str(" ")
    d = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    v = 0
    if x1<0:
        x1 = -x1
        v = 1
    while x1>0:
        s = d[x1%s2] + s
        x1 = x1//s2
    if v == 1:
        s = "-" + s
    print(s)
```

Его надо дополнить, чтобы при некорректных данных (например 200, 2, 10) выводилось -1, а не ошибка. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x, s1, s2 = map(int,input().split())
x = str(x)
try:
    x1 = int(x, s1)
except ValueError:
    print(-1)
else:
    
    if s2 == 10:
        print(x1)
    else:
        s = str(" ")
        d = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        v = 0
        if x1<0:
            x1 = -x1
            v = 1
        while x1>0:
            s = d[x1%s2] + s
            x1 = x1//s2
        if v == 1:
            s = "-" + s
        print(s)
```

Comment: а что значит except ValueError?

Comment: @Горностайка это перехват ошибки. То есть программа ожидает, что может крашнуться, отлавливает эту ошибку и вместо краша выполняет то, что в этом блоке